# Can I use a MobileFirst app without the MobileFirst server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Can I consume a web service in a MobileFirst application without a MobileFirst server?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use your MobileFirst app without the need to connect to a MobileFirst server.

The drawback of not using the MobileFirst server is that you'll be loosing all of the features it provides like **authentication**, **security**, **adapters**, **unified push notifications**, **direct update** (for hybrid), **remote disable**, and other features.

If you want to make a request to any endpoint you can use `WLResourceRequest` (available from version 7.0 onwards) or any other native method to make HTTP requests.

Information on how to use `WLResourceRequest`

**Android**: 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLResourceRequest.html

**Hybrid**:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.0.0%2F9-0-0-1-31

**iOS**: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/interface_w_l_resource_request.html%23a004749b662c6f4a55a3b76e47f7e6062?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

If the call is for example to an external resource you can use the same plain regular AJAX calls as you would anywhere else.

If the resource is protected by MobileFirst Platform, then you must use adapters. Adapters must go through the MobileFirst Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like simple IDE to develop application(Native and hybrid).You can use client side API also that do not connect to the mobilefirst server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a mobile first app if you are using MF 7.0 or higher without a server, as soon as you launch the app it invokes an authorization request something like following:

> << domain >>/<< context >>/authorization/v1/clients/instance

Which connects to your workflight server and if it doesnt get response it will fail.

As far as invoking a web service is concerned that is just javascript if you are doing hybrid you can use AJAX as mentioned in another answer. If you are building native IOS or Android you can invoke http request using sdk libraries.

Cheers !

Comment: That's not true. It will invoke such a request ONLY if you have `connectOnStartup:true` in **initOptions.js** or use `WL.Client.connect`.

Comment: connectOnStartup is deprecated we are not using it anymore. We learned this from another answer posted by you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371335/wl-client-connect-sending-request

Comment: I know it's deprecated. :) Deprecated means it will be removed in a future version (and is indeed not used anymore in v8.0).

Comment: Let us know if there is way to avoid application not sending this URL, as pasted in previous comment reference to your other answer.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. Feel free to open a PMR so IBM L2 support could help you.